# Inquiry about Kentico9 Caching

Tags: c#, caching, kentico

I'm using Kentico 9 and trying to test caching. I would like to ask about how to replace the existing cache if a new value is entered.

Recently was trying to cache with this code:

```
CacheHelper.Cache(cs => getCachingValue(cs, cacheValue), new CacheSettings(10, "cacheValue"));

public string getCachingValue(CacheSettings cs, string result) {
    string cacheValue= result;     

    if (cs.Cached)
    {
        cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("cacheValue");
    }

    return cacheValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When caching data you need to setup correct cache dependencies. For example this is cache dependency for all users:

```
if (cs.Cached)
        {
            cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("cms.user|all");
        }
```

This will drop cache whenever user has been updated or created. So next time you call the method it will get data from database and cache it again until cache expires or someone adds/updates user.

So you don't need to take care about replacing/updating cached data - appropriate mechanism is already there.

See cache dependencies in [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/configuring-kentico/optimizing-website-performance/configuring-caching/setting-cache-dependencies).

Comment: Also in your example you pass a value you want to cache into getCachingValue method. The data you want to store into a cache should be retrieved (from database) inside of that method.

Answer (score 2):

Since your cache dependency is called `"cacheValue"`, you need to "touch" that particular cache key, to force the cache to clear.

When the value you are caching changes (the value you provide to the `string result` parameter of the `getCachingValue` method), call the `CacheHelper.TouchKey` method to force the cache to clear:

```cs
CacheHelper.TouchKey("cacheValue");
```

*(You should also consider changing the name of the cache key, to prevent confusion)*

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that if your cache key is "cacheValue" then any call that is made to this will always be the same 'hit.'  The CacheSetting key is it's 'unique identifier' you could say, and the Cache Depenency is how it automatically resets.

So for example, say you cache a function that adds two values (wouldn't really need to cache this, but for an example where the input changes)

If you have a cache value for your "AddTwoValues(int a, int b)" of

```
CacheHelper.Cache(cs => AddTwoValuesHelper(cs, a, b), new CacheSettings(10, "cacheValue"));
```

The first call will cache the the value of the call (say you pass it 1 and 2), so it caches "3" for the key "cacheValue"

Second call if you pass it 3, 5, the cache key is still "cacheValue" so it will assume it's the same call as the first and return 3, and not even try to add 3+5.

I usually append any parameters to the cache key.

```
CacheHelper.Cache(cs => AddTwoValuesHelper(cs, a, b), new CacheSettings(10, string.Format("AddTwoValues|{0}|{1}", a, b)));
```

This way if i call it with 1 and 2, twice, the first it will processes and cache "3" for the key "AddTwoValues|1|2", and when called again the key will match so it will just return the cached value.

If you call with different parameters, then the cache key will be different.

Make sense?

The other answers of course talk on the cache dependency in the helper function:

```
if (cs.Cached)
        {
            cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("cms.user|all");
        }
```

Which identify how it automatically clears (if you do cms.users|all as the dependency, whenever a user is changed, this cache automatically clears itself)